# Bootstrap carousel with slide previews

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3, carousel

i want to use the Bootstrap carousel to show a preview of the next/prev slides beside the active slide.

Like in this example:

[image]

Unfortunately, I have not found a solution. Is it even possible with the Bootstrap carousel?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, I found a stand alone solution: http://www.owlcarousel.owlgraphic.com/

If someone is looking for a same solution...